# Can I ship Alimentum Ready to Feed to my house during 85-100 Fahrenheit days?

Tags: formula

I have a 7 month old who feeds on Alimentum Ready to Feed. The manufacturer said that the unopened storage temperature is up to 95 degree Fahrenheit. I live in New Orleans where we commonly have 88-100 Fahrenheit top heat days during summer. I get the formula shipped to my house via Amazon and Walmart. Should I be concerned how it’s shipped to my house? Will it spoil in the shipping trucks or Amazon or Walmart storage facilities? It’s unreliable to depend on it being in stock at local stores.

Comment: Perhaps ask Amazon and Walmart about their storage processes.

Comment: There's a contact number for your product's information. *Spoil* is a vague term, and it implies the product is unusabie, which is often not the case with this kind of problem, but it's a possibility.  if the effect of high temperatures is significant (spoilage or loss of significant amount of nutritional value), they can answer that.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: it's highly unlikely that the company would state anything other than "product should only be used as specified on the label". Typically environmental requirements are set upfront and all subsequent development and testing is done to this target. That's the only storage temperature against which the product is fully tested and certified (which costs a lot of time and money). Even if they are reasonably sure that it's "perfectly fine at 105F for a few days", they could never say that in public: it would create a massive legal exposure risk.

Comment: @Hilmar - It's not as cut and dry as you think. There are many, many products that are fine well after their expiration dates, for example. This is especially true of food items. I have not as much doubt as you do about contacting the manufacturer. What's the harm in trying?